# Hibernate Validator on Jersey with Grizzly 2 validating slow

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, groovy, hibernate-validator

I seem to have run into a bit of a snag concerning Hibernate validation. Consider the following endpoint method (in groovy):

```
@POST
@Path("authenticate")
authenticate(User entity) {
    if (entity == null) return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build()
    def validation = Validator.validate(entity)

    if(!validation.valid) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(validation.invalidationTokens).build()
    }
    return Response.ok(entity).build()
}
```

This code works, but every second time I call this endpoint, it takes about 300ms longer to process, then the next request will be extremely fast again, then slow again, and so on... The endpoint class is application scoped, as I first thought it could be due to it creating a new instance again or something but that's not it.

Here you can see it happen (I use Postman to test the request): [image: Inconsistent process time for validation]

I have determined it is because of the validator. When I leave out the validation in the endpoint method posted above, it is consistently fast.

Below is the validator class I use to validate and return violated constraints.

```
private static javax.validation.Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

private Validator() {

}

public static <E> ValidationResult validate(E element, Class<?> ... groups) {
    return ValidationResult.fromConstraintViolations(validator.validate(element, groups));
}
```

Currently the only field being validated in the User entity is:

```
@NotNull(message = "username.empty")
private String username;
```

I would normally use injection to get a validator but I can't seem to get it to work on this configuration.

I use the following relevant maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I have not mentioned that I do my serialization to json via Gson. I was tinkering around in my gson-based bodywriter and I seem to have eliminated the inconsistency (however I haven't actually changed any procedures). I will post this as an answer when I know for sure that this was the fix.

Comment: Hey, did you gain any further insights on this one (e.g. by doing some profiling etc.)? I'd be very glad to learn about any performance issues, for sure there are things in the HV code base we can improve.

Comment: @Gunnar I have not been able to reproduce the slow performance. I do not really understand why it was slow with Gson, considering I didn't change anything except changing Gson to also serialize jax-rs ResponseBuilder instances. Which is, as far as I know, completely unrelated to hibernate validator. I may have changed something else aswell but it was definetely simmilar to this.